# Inter process communication for web and window application

Tags: asp.net, inter-process-communicat

I want to send data from intranet web application that is running on server to a window application running on local machine??
which would be the best way to perform this task?
i am comfortable with wcf services.
can anyone please post any link to get some hint regarding this ..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ZeroMQ (if you're on .NET, look at NetMQ).

Comment: can i do with the use of wcf too.